# Append value to list with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, append

```
allname = []
alltel = []
allemail = []

for link in docdetail:
            name = soup.h1.contents[1]
            tel = soup.find('a', class_='tel').string
            email = soup.find('a', class_='email').string
            allname.append(name)
            alltel.append(tel)
            allemail.append(email)
```

I want to append name to allname, tel to alltel, email to allemail after every for loop. But it is possible that the returned value for name/tel/email is empty, then he order of attributes may mess up. 
I want to assign "NA" to the variable if the returned values are empty. How should I write a code for this precisely?

Comment: Can you show the html? Also your accepted answer could not possibly do what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `try, except` to catch your exceptions as follows.

```
allname = []
alltel = []
allemail = []

for link in docdetail:
        name = soup.h1.contents[1]
        tel = soup.find('a', class_='tel').string
        email = soup.find('a', class_='email').string
        allname.append(name)
        try:
            alltel.append(tel)
        except:
            alltel.append('N/A')
        try:
            allemail.append(email)
        except:
            allemail.append('N/A')
```

Then you will have as much data in your fields as there is available. You can also use a `try, except` for the name if it not certain that it is there. This way will preserve your data in the same index - that is that entry `alltel[x]`, `allemail[x]` and `allname[x]` all refer to the same entity.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing? How is it going to error appending?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use for loop, so whatever be the number of values it will be appended to array, if there's no value none will be appended :

```
for single_name in name:
    allname.append(single_name)
for single_tel in tel:
    alltel.append(single_tel)
for single_email in email:
    allemail.append(single_email)
```

Comment: If the first item has a name but no number and the second field has a name but no email the first field will have the 2nd field's number will be in the first fields index.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function to verify the attribute, See below example.

```
def validate_string(attr):
    if attr.strip() == '':
        return 'NA'
    else:
        return attr.strip()

allname = []
alltel = []
allemail = []

for link in docdetail:
    name = soup.h1.contents[1]
    tel = soup.find('a', class_='tel').string
    email = soup.find('a', class_='email').string
    allname.append(validate_string(name))
    alltel.append(validate_string(tel))
    allemail.append(validate_string(email))
```

Answer (score -1):

soup.find() returns a None value if there is no match. An attribute error occurs when applying the .string method to a None value. You can catch it this way:

```
allname = []
alltel = []
allemail = []

for link in docdetail:
            name = soup.h1.contents[1]
            tel = soup.find('a', class_='tel').string
            email = soup.find('a', class_='email').string

            try:
                allname.append(name)
            except AttributeError:
                allname.append(None)

            try:
                allemail.append(name)
            except AttributeError:
                allemail.append(None)

            try:
                allname.append(name)
            except AttributeError:
                allname.append(None)
```

Comment: If you want the requested NA value, simply change None to "NA" in the except clauses.